# Laravel набить массив

Tags: php, laravel, orm

создаю рулетку игр, интересует такой вопрос.
У меня есть в таблице из 5 игр, каким образом можно вернуть 20 игр в рандомном порядке?

Comment: Что у вас есть? Что вы пытались сделать? Если я правильно понял то просто продублируйте эти 5 записей 4 раза, и перемешайте массив в случайном порядке

Answer (score 1):

откройте для себя коллекции https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections

```
$collection = collect([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]);
$collection->random(3) - вернёт 3 рандомных элемента
```

Comment: я знаю что такое коллекции, меня именно интересует как набить массив искусственно из миграции, у меня есть кейсы и игры которые подвязаны к кейсу, мне нужно вытянуть игры ну скажем 40 шт, а игр который подвязаны к кейсу 5 и мне нужно чтоб он набил массив в любом порядке и любым кол-во игр

Comment: Используйте наполнение данными на стадии сидирования

Answer (score 0):

Перемешиваете массив, выводите элементы. Делаете это в цикле.

```
 <?php
    $array = array( "1" => "Game 1",  
                    "2" => "Game 2", 
                    "3" => "Game 3", 
                    "4" => "Game 4", 
                    "5" => "Game 5",
                    );
                    
    for ($i = 0; $i < 4; $i++){   
        shuffle($array);
        foreach ($array as $game){                
            echo $game;
            
        }
    }
```

Comment: и зачем это нужно ?